# On scroll div colour change

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to change the colour of btns within a menu dependant on scroll according to the div.. but not working right.. [Added a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se9PY.png) to help understand what im trying to do.

html menu btns:

```
<div class="left-bar-preview">
    <div class="image mini-sub"><img class="icon-image" src="../images/human.svg" width="42">
    </div>
    <a class="mini-sub w-inline-block" href="#" id="name-btn">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <a class="mini-sub w-inline-block" href="#" id="style-btn">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <a class="mini-sub w-inline-block" href="#" id="position-btn">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <a class="mini-sub w-inline-block" href="#" id="information-btn">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <a class="mini-sub w-inline-block" href="#" id="budget-btn">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <a class="mini-sub w-inline-block" href="#" id="photos-btn">
      <div></div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

html div:

```
<div class="name preview-content w-clearfix" data-ix="on-scroll-light-up" id="name-div">
    <h4 class="field-box spacing"><strong>Name</strong></h4>
    <h4>My new tattoo</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="name preview-content w-clearfix" id="style-div">
    <h4 class="field-box spacing"><strong>Style</strong></h4>
    <h4>Heading</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="name preview-content w-clearfix" id="position-div">
    <h4 class="field-box spacing"><strong>Position on body</strong></h4>
    <h4>Black &amp; White</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="name preview-content w-clearfix" id="side-div">
    <h4 class="field-box spacing"><strong>Side</strong></h4>
    <h4>Right</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="name preview-content w-clearfix" id="information-div">
    <h4 class="field-box spacing"><strong>Brief</strong></h4>
    <h4>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."<br>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."<br>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="name preview-content w-clearfix" id="budget-div">
    <h4 class="field-box spacing"><strong>Budget</strong></h4>
    <h4>$200-$400</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="name preview-content w-clearfix" id="photos-div">
    <h4 class="field-box spacing"><strong>Photos</strong></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){;
    w = Math.floor( $(window).scrollTop() );  
    $('.mini-sub').css( 'background-color', '' ); 
    if(w<=$("#name-div").offset().top){
         $("#name-btn").css( 'background-color', '#972663' );   
    }else if(w<=$("#style-div").offset().top){
         $("#style-btn").css( 'background-color', '#972663' );   
    }else if(w<=$("#position-div").offset().top){
         $("#position-btn").css( 'background-color', '#972663' );   
    }else if(w<=$("#information-div").offset().top){
         $("#information-btn").css( 'background-color', '#972663' );   
    }else if(w<=$("#budget-div").offset().top){
         $("#budget-btn").css( 'background-color', '#972663' ); 
    }else{
         $("#photos-div").css( 'background-color', '#972663' );   
         }

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle as well?

Comment: Use the SO snippet editor. That way you can create an inline fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/scoe1grt/ @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan

best i could do on the fly

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for -
**JS code:**

```
$(".right").scroll(function(){
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
if(st <= 50){
    $(".A").css("color", "red")
}
else if(st <= 100){
    $(".B").css("color", "red")
}
else if(st <= 150){
    $(".C").css("color", "red")
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/qudnauvq/

Comment: more something like this  :
http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/1pdq2van/

Cant get it to fly though

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification to @MotaBOS's solution

```
$(".right").scroll(function(){
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".left span").css("color", "black")
if(st <= 50){

    $(".A").css("color", "red")
}
else if(st <= 100){
    $(".B").css("color", "red")
}
else {
    $(".C").css("color", "red")
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it cannot be determinant by pixels as the divs may change size, i thought there was a way to do it by the id?